# CRT not initialized

Tags: c++, crt

I'm trying to compile one project with MSVC 2010, compilation is ok, but when I try to run the app, it gives me CRT not initialized error. It is a console application, so I tried to specify mainCRTStartup as Entry Point, but it didn't help.
In the same solution there are other projects, and they don't have such a problem. The difference which I see between them is that one which is not working, uses boost. Boost v1.38.0 if this is important. Runtime Library is Multi-threaded DLL.

Linker command line is:

```
/OUT:"D:\temp\ghost\Release\ghost.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"..\zlib\lib" /LIBPATH:"..\mysql\lib\opt" /LIBPATH:"..\boost\lib" "ws2_32.lib" "winmm.lib" "zdll.lib" "StormLibRAS.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" "D:\temp\ghost\bncsutil\vc8_build\Release\BNCSutil.lib" /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"Release\ghost.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"D:\temp\ghost\Release\ghost.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /PGD:"D:\temp\ghost\Release\ghost.pgd" /LTCG /TLBID:1 /ENTRY:"mainCRTStartup" /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE
```

Comment: are you using `CreateThread` by any chance?

Comment: seems like no, at least nothing found in search

Comment: I don't see boost lib-s in the cmd line. Do you load them dynamically with LoadLibrary?

Comment: Getting any compilation warnings?

Comment: If any answer was correct or helpful please accept or upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set your PATH to boost/lib before launching so that it can find the boost library.

Answer (score 0):

Are you compiling with `/DBOOST_THREAD_USE_DLL /DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` set?

If Boost thinks you are using statically linked CRT and you are using MT DLL this could cause this type of issue.

Also remember to clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was very simple: Spy++ was open, so shutdown Spy++ solves the problem!